# Got issue $injector:unpr Unknown Provider for $cookies in ngCookies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, angular-cookies

[Click here to see error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8r5z.png)

Got error $injector:unpr Unknown Provider for $cookies

i added the ngcookies module in my app.js file and using the $cookie service in my controller but i cant create a cookie 
throws error when cookie service is injecting in my controller

app.js

```
angular.module('advogeApp', [
'ngResource',
'ngCookies',
'editorCtrl',
'SigninCtrl',
'SignupCtrl']).config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $cookies){
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
}]);
```

controller.js

```
var app = angular.module('advogeApp');
app.controller('SigninCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$cookies', '$location', function($scope, $http, $cookies, $location) {$scope.loginData = function () {
            angular.element('#signin').modal("hide");
            $http({
                method : 'POST',
                url : '/proxy/',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'endpoint' : '/login/'},
                data : JSON.stringify({email : $scope.userEmail, password : $scope.userPwd}),
            }).then(function(response){

                    $cookies.put('set-cookie', response.data.headers['set-cookie']);

                if (response.data.body.info == "sucessfully logged in") {
                            $location.path('/dashboard');
                     } else {
                            $scope.logininfo = response.data.info;
                            console.log(response.data);
                     }
            },function(response){
                console.log(response);
            });
```

Please help to slove this error

Answer (score 0):

You have missed some injections here :

app.js

```
angular.module('advogeApp', [
'ngResource',
'ngCookies',
'editorCtrl',
'SigninCtrl',
'SignupCtrl']).config(['$routeProvider','$httpProvider', '$cookies', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $cookies){
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
}]);
```

EDIT (try this)

controller.js

```
var app = angular.module('advogeApp', ['ngCookies']);
```

Maybe it's overriding module ?

Comment: Could u tell any missed injections

Comment: Look the differnece between my code and yours, I have just added this : `'$httpProvider', '$cookies'`

Comment: @stevee Pitis 
problem is with the controller part when im injecting the cookie service into it throws the above error

Comment: Yes I saw, but btw these injections were missing ^^

I'll edit my answer try this.

Comment: the page isn't loading
i tried it before as u suggested but it wont work.

Comment: and what is the result if you chain your controller with the config ?

Comment: response is $injector:modulerr Module Error.

 http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=advogeApp&p1=Error%…(http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8080%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A319)
and page isn't loading

Comment: there is a mess somewhere in your code. I need to see more of your code to tell you what is wrong.